# How can one believe one won't be born again having attained Vaikuntha?

Tags: vishnu, vishnu-purana, vaikuntha

Jai-Vijay were dwelling in Vaikuntha with Lord Vishnu who happened to be born again due to curse by KumAras. Vaikuntha is said to be the final destination by many philosophies. But if that is the final destination, why they happened to be born again considering any reason. (even curse)

So, Is Vaikuntha a temporarily place? Or in other words, is there no guarantee one won't born again even after attaining Vaikuntha?

Comment: I think Vaikunta of Jaya Vijaya is the lowest one or the earthly one or Sweta Dvipa. Skanda Purana has legends where some Jivas returned even after reaching earthly Kailasa.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Well, I don't believe in such destinations to be the ultimate let it be even Kailash. Supreme abode can't have any form. But I am curious to know the arguments/opinions of the philosophies who call Vaikuntha supreme abode.

Comment: There are many Kailasas and Vaikuntas. This is my point.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Actually, according to the philosophy I believe in, Liberation is to mingle with Shiva tattva or Shakti tattva or Sadashiva tattva or Ishwar tattva or Shuddhavidya tattva & this tattvas transcends space-time, so final destination is formless. Maybe what you read were pointing towards this only.

Comment: I think Puranas explicitly mention about Lokas. For example, Shiva Purana says there are two Kailasas. Maybe Vaishnava Puranas also say the same. This is different from Philosophies. Philosophies are interpretations. But let's see if there are different Vaikuntas or how different philosophies explain this.

Comment: There are only two Vaikunthas @TheDestroyer One is the milky ocean and the supreme abode Paramapadam. The Paramapadam is the place where on reaching there, we won't return. That is the supreme destination.

Comment: @NogShine So where these 2 guys were dwelling?

Comment: @Rohit. Why don't you believe that the supreme abode has a form? The Vedas, Bhagavad Gita give the description of this. Don't you believe in it? And the people who believe Vaikuntha being paramapadam are Vaishnavas. Not following a man made philosophy. They were definitely not guarding Paramapadam.

Comment: @NogShine Good question, Actually one can't be blissful being incomplete- bliss is by product of completedness & form is bounded or incomplete which can't grant infinite bliss which is unbounded, that's why limited can't offer unlimited & so form can't offer which is formless. And about philosophies, Even divine philosophies bewilder a man. Brihaspati being a Guru propagated Charvakas. On the other hand, one get self realization without any philosophies.

Comment: Also, the attitude of attaching branded reliable tag on what we believe is a sign of fear or insecurity which wants to build a wall of protection around our ideas - Fear of not being false. This fear what makes us fanatic, commercial ( having attitude - will follow you only if you are true or supreme). True surrender never builds a wall of protection around itself. It just knows to assimilate into the God, it knows to take risks, to tread on the unknown path.

Comment: @Mr.Sigma. Jaya and Vijaya were dwelling in Ksheersagara (the Milky ocean as Sarvabhouma says).